# How to create a Solana Token + Listing on Dexscreen?

Tags: mint, devnet, swap, fees, liquiditypool

I need a little help. My whole project seems to be harder than I thought.

I want to create a coin on the Solana blockchain. Since the Solana code is a lot heavier than ETH etc. - there are many generators that make it easy to create.

How and where do I best create my Solana token so that I can:

- Simply create
- Create a liquidity pool
- Revoke Mint Authority

It should be inexpensive. Some generators want up to 3 Solana!

Additionally I would like to list my coin on DexScreener. - How expensive will that be?

Questions:

Where is the cheapest way to create my coin?

How much budget do I have to expect to be listed on DexScreener in the end?

I hope someone can help me!

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Use https://pump.fun , costs only 0.02 sol, but  won't be listed in public market till u hit 75k mcap.

Comment: u would have to pay for dexscreener listing tho

Answer (score 0):

I'm using https://solcarry.us, it costs me only 0.3 SOL to create a new market instead of 3 SOL.